# Counting duplicate and unique values within groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
DF1:
Class | Age | City        | Color
  A   | 20  | Los Angeles | Blue
  A   | 20  | Los Angeles | Blue
  A   | 20  | Los Angeles | Red
  B   | 25  | Phoenix     | Yellow
```

I'd like to get a unique count of every duplicate and unique value so the output looks like this:

```
DF2:
Class | Age | City        | Color   | Count
  A   | 20  | Los Angeles | Blue    |  2
  A   | 20  | Los Angeles | Red     |  1
  B   | 25  | Phoenix     | Yellow  |  1
```

In this case, `Class` A, `Age` 20, `City` Los Angeles, and `Color` Blue shows up twice. I've tried using `nunique` but my output did not collapse duplicate vales together.

```
df = df.groupby(['Class', 'Age', 'City', 'Color']).nunique()
```

Comment: What did `df.groupby(['Class', 'Age', 'City', 'Color']).nunique()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
result = df.groupby(['Class', 'Age', 'City', 'Color']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  Class  Age         City   Color  Count
0     A   20  Los Angeles    Blue      2
1     A   20  Los Angeles     Red      1
2     B   25      Phoenix  Yellow      1
```